# Why isn't there a deb package for rosinstall?

Tags: ros, installation, rosinstall, roscore

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The install/setup instructions tell users to:

```
sudo apt-get install python-setuptools
sudo easy_install -U rosinstall
```

It seems like something that should be part of ros core, or at the very least have a deb package associated.

Is there any particular reason for this?

Is this something I should file a feature request ticket for?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10134/why-isn%27t-there-a-deb-package-for-rosinstall?/) by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2743 on 2011-06-01

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This would make a good ticket, though it something that is currently being worked on.

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-06-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

BTW, you can easily generate a debian package for rosinstall yourself:

```
sudo apt-get install python-stdeb
pypi-install --keep rosinstall
find /tmp -name 'python-rosinstall*.deb'
```

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2011-07-18

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) on 2011-07-18**:
Awesome : )